# NivoSlider for Umbraco - Media library can't find Media Type

Tags: umbraco

I'm using NivoSlider for Umbraco and I've ran into a problem.
On the documentation, it's written that after creating a Media Type, it should be possible to create a node of that in a folder in Media library but that is not the case with me. I can only create a Folder, an Image and a File.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

NivoSlider can be found [here](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/nivoslider-for-umbraco/)

Comment: Please share what specific exception you're receiving and show us some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Apperently I was supposed to create a folder with Media type as object, not a file inside a folder